# Show Active Sessions Glassfish in JSF application (Java)

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

You can view statistics in the Glassfish Admin Console. You've to activate the monitoring first:

Configurations -> server-config -> Monitoring -> Set Monitoring level to HIGH for Web Container

Now you can see the statistics under server -> Monitor

[Active Sessions Glassfish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgBaH.png)

The question is: How i can get this number (active sessions) in an JSF application and show it in an .xhtml file?

Thanks!